# Applescript and Microsoft Word

Tags: macos, ms-word, applescript

I'm working on a applescript to update the content of a document in Microsoft Word. The updating process is quite long (might take more than 5s). So I want to prevent users to change anything during the updating. Do you know whether Microsoft or Applescript a function like that?

In Windows, I can just display a User Form (which is a dialog telling that "we are updating... ") and close that form when it's done. However, I don't know whether I can do the same in Mac (with Applescript alone).

Answer (score 0):

When you say "applescript", I don't know if you mean "plain" applescript or the AppleScriptObjC version.  If you mean the latter, then I know ways to do it.
One way I've used during slow processes is to put an overlay view over the whole content view of the window.  I make it translucent white to partially obscure the window, and put some kind of message (and maybe a progress indicator) on it.  You can just use an NSBox (of the custom type) in IB to make this, and then make a subclass of NSBox to color the view and override mouseDown:.  MouseDown:, doesn't need to have any code in it, just by overriding it, you capture any key and mouse events so they don't accumulate on the event queue, and get used by the view below after your overlay goes away. Here's code I've used:

```
script  Overlay
property parent : class "NSBox"

on awakeFromNib()
    set overlayColor to current application's NSColor's colorWithCalibratedWhite_alpha_(1,.8)
    setFillColor_(overlayColor)
end

on mouseDown_(theEvent)
    --log "mouseDown"
end
```

end script

I have this view as the top most view in the view hierarchy, and set its hidden property to true until I want to show it.